# How to compare three PHP arrays and group results that are not repeated in different new arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array that has three arrays inside.

```
$rubros array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "2"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "4"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "5"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "6"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "7"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "8"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "9"
    }
    [8]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "11"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "2"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "3"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "4"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "5"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "6"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "7"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "8"
    }
    [8]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "9"
    }
    [9]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "11"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "2"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "4"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "5"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "6"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "7"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "8"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "9"
    }
    [8]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(2) "10"
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to compare each of the three internal arrays to obtain this arrays:

> Array 1: List of all common elements of the three internal arrays,
> like:

1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9

> Array 2: A list of all elements that are only in the first array:

It will be empty.

> Array 3: A list of all elements that are only in the second array:

3

> Array 4: A list of all elements that are only in the third array:

10

> Array 5: A list of all elements that are shared by more than one
> array:

11

I tried doing  `$i = array_diff($rubros[1], $rubros[2], $rubros[3]);`

But I get an empty array...?

Comment: There's no `11` in provided arrays.

Comment: array_diff compares standard arrays to each other... it does not compare multidimensional arrays $rubros[1][0]['idRubro'] = "1" , if you loose the 'idRubro' key and just let it be like $rubros[1][0] = "1"; $rubros[1][1] = "2" ; it should work...

Comment: Instead of : $rubros array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["idRubro"]=>      string(1) "1"
    } How about just doing: $rubros array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>      string(1) "1"
    } etc... loose one dimension of a repetitive key and be able to compare.

Comment: Thanks @u_mulder, I corrected the error.

Comment: Thanks @Shlomtzion, I'll try that and see what happens...

Comment: You were right @Shlomtzion! It worked!!

Comment: Could @Shlomtzion or the OP post an answer so this can be marked as resolved?

Comment: @Rosamunda Could you? :)

Answer (score 0):

The multi-dimensional array $rubros

```
$rubros = [
  [
    ["idRubro" => "1"],
    ["idRubro" => "2"],
    ["idRubro" => "4"],
    ["idRubro" => "5"],
    ["idRubro" => "6"],
    ["idRubro" => "7"],
    ["idRubro" => "8"],
    ["idRubro" => "9"],
  ],
  [
    ["idRubro" => "1"],
    ["idRubro" => "2"],
    ["idRubro" => "3"],
    ["idRubro" => "4"],
    ["idRubro" => "5"],
    ["idRubro" => "6"],
    ["idRubro" => "7"],
    ["idRubro" => "8"],
    ["idRubro" => "9"],
    ["idRubro" => "11"],
  ],
  [
    ["idRubro" => "1"],
    ["idRubro" => "2"],
    ["idRubro" => "4"],
    ["idRubro" => "5"],
    ["idRubro" => "6"],
    ["idRubro" => "7"],
    ["idRubro" => "8"],
    ["idRubro" => "9"],
    ["idRubro" => "10"],
  ],
];
```

must be converted into an array with 3 one-dimensional sub-arrays.

```
$arrIdRub = [];
foreach($rubros as $key => $arr){
  $arrIdRub[$key] = array_column($arr,"idRubro");
}
```

Various array functions can be used with these arrays.
List of all common elements:

```
$arr1 = array_intersect(...$arrIdRub);  //Arr1
/*
array (
  0 => "1",
  1 => "2",
  2 => "4",
  3 => "5",
  4 => "6",
  5 => "7",
  6 => "8",
  7 => "9",
)
*/
```

Array 2..4:

```
$arr2 = array_diff(...$arrIdRub); // []

$arr3 = array_diff($arrIdRub[1],$arrIdRub[0],$arrIdRub[2]); //[2 => "3", 9 => "11"]


$arr4 = array_diff($arrIdRub[2],$arrIdRub[0],$arrIdRub[1]); // [8 => "10"]
```

List of all elements that are shared by more than one array.

```
$arrAll = array_count_values(array_merge(...$arrIdRub));  //merge and count
$arrAll = array_filter($arrAll,function($val){return $val >=2;});  //filter 2 or more
$arrAll = array_keys($arrAll);
```